# Vim snippets plugin

Tags: vim, code-snippets, snipmate, vim-plugin

I know there is some vim plugins that implements TextMate-like snippets feature. The popular are: **snipMate, snippetsEmu, neocomplcache, UltiSnips and xptemplate.** 
What is the best and why? Consider using this with others plugins like **SuperTab, AutoComplPop and pathogen**. Have you ever tried those plugins? What do you prefer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many things, you'll find that personal preference wins out at the end of the day. Personally, I prefer snippentsEmu for one reason: it supports dynamic snippets. For example a Python formatting string `"foo %s %s"` will (can) dynamically add a placeholder for each `%s`.

snippetsEmu is certainly not perfect - I have come across a few bugs and annoyances - but it works well with superTab. I honestly don't have much experience with the other plug-ins mentioned (although I believe I've tried them all), so I can't really give a fair comparison.